# Javascript Google Api, How to use Q?

Tags: javascript, google-api-client

Been working with the google api client for websites, and I'm looking to get a list of folders from the user's drive account, and everything in `gapi` is setup properly to make requests. The issue is that I don't understand the documentation of the `q` request object.

from what I understand, I should be using the `drive/files/list` endpoint, and passing options to filter out all the non-folders.

From what I can glean from the docs is that my request should look something like this:

```
gapi.client.drive.files.list({
   q: 'mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
   pageSize: 25,
   fields: 'nextPageToken, files(name, kind, parents)'
}).then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

but I continue to get this error:

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

I've tried to define `q` as `'mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.folder"'` and `'mimeType=\'application/vnd.google-apps.folder\''`

But I get the same `error in q` result. Could someone please show me how to use the `q` parameter? I'm sure it's really important to searching in the google api.

Comment: Your query should have quotes around "application/vnd.google-apps.folder", but you already said you tried that. I suggest you try again, because it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appropriate method:

It turns out I had not actually tried the double quoted version, which was eventually the answer.

```
gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    q: 'mimeType="applicaton/vnd.google-apps.folder"',
    pageSize: 25,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(name, kind, parents)',
}).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to provide the solution. That said, you should explain what you've changed rather than making the answer a game of spot-the-difference :)